# Trying to make a unit converter in python but the input value is not being acted upon

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and this is what I have written,

```
print(" Please type : \nMeters = M \nCentimeters = CM \nKilometers = KM ")

print("Please enter the unit of the input value")
unit1 = input()
print("Please enter the unit of the output value")
unit2 = input()
print("Please enter the value")
value = int(input())

def calculator():
    if unit1 == "M" and unit2 == "CM":
        value == value * 100
    elif unit1 == "M" and unit2 == "KM":
        value == value / 1000
    elif unit1 == "M" and unit2 == "M": 
        value == value
    elif unit1 == "CM" and unit2 == "M":
        value == value / 1000
    elif unit1 == "CM" and unit2 == "KM":
        value == value / 100000
    elif unit1 == "CM" and unit2 == "CM":
        value == value
    elif unit1 == "KM" and unit2 == "CM":
        value == value * 100000
    elif unit1 == "KM" and unit2 == "M":
        value == value * 1000
    elif unit1 == "KM" and unit2 == "KM":
        value == value
    else:
        print("The unit entered was not valid")

calculator()
print("Your value is...")
print(value, unit2)
```

When I use this code no effect is taken on the value. The value always outputs as what it was inputted as.

Thanks

Comment: There are a variety of issues with this code. I'd suggest reading up on assignment, booleans, and scoping in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`value` and `unit2` are the global variables which the user has given as input. You made a function `calculator` but you are not passing any values to it and thus only `print(value, unit2)` gets evaluated which results in printing the user defined value of `value` and `unit2`.

You need to pass `value`, `unit1` & `unit2` in the calculator method and also need to take these variables as arguments while calculating your final value. Lastly you need to `return` the `value` back to where it came from.

Basically your code should look like this:

```
def calculator(value, unit1, unit2):
    # your if-elif loop
    else:
        return("The unit entered was not valid")
    return value

print("Your value is...")
print(calculator(value, unit1, unit2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do this.Still I will point out 1 serious error.

```
value == value * 100
```

Should be

```
value = value * 100
```